# SFTP Authentication using private RSA Key in libcurl

Tags: c, curl, libcurl, sftp

I am using `stfp server` but it requires RSA key authentication, Here i want to upload files on my `sftp` server.

So please any body can tell me how can i authenticate my SFTP server using private key of `RSA` programmatically in C. I want to do this thing in C

i am using this [link](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/fileupload.html) for refernce

But Here its not mentioned how to do authentication of this SFTP using RSA key.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For public key authentication I add the following options:

```
const char* path_to_my_public_key = "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub";
const char* path_to_my_private_key = "~/.ssh/id_rsa";

curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSH_AUTH_TYPES, CURLSSH_AUTH_PUBLICKEY);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE, path_to_my_public_key);
curl_easy_setopt(m_curl, CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE, path_to_my_private_key);
```